# Error decoding JSON in PHP: "unexpected character"

Tags: php, json

I have a strange JSON decoding problem in PHP. A certain JSON file (and only this) produces reliably a decoding error. The PHP part is nothing special:

```
$data = array();
if (is_file(DIR.'config.json')) {
    $data = json_decode(DIR.'config.json');
}

// diagnostics:
var_dump($data); // --> NULL (would be array() if decoding didn't happen)
var_dump(json_last_error()); // --> int(4) === JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX
var_dump(json_last_error_msg()); // --> string(20) "unexpected character"
echo file_get_contents(DIR.'config.json'); // --> '["a"]'
```

What I've tried:

- Simplify JSON. The content of the file now is `["a"]`.
- validate JSON, just to be sure, in four validators, including jsonlint.com and pasting it in browser console
- No BOM, plain ASCII file
- has read rights. The above `echo` works just fine.
- completely *independent* of JSON file's content.
- path is correct. Proven by above `echo` statement. JSON file is in the docroot.

Unfortunately PHP's JSON lib doesn't state errors more precisely, so I have no idea, what *really* causes the error.

Has anyone an idea, how I could proceed?

Comment: To close or not to close, that is the question. Do you think, it's relevant (and findable!) for other users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not decoding the file contents, but rather the name of the file itself, which is why you're getting null. Your code should be:

```
$data = array();
if (is_file(DIR.'config.json')) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents(DIR.'config.json'));
}
```

Comment: Oh crap. Thanks for the catch! I was way too much in Pythons `json.load()` to notice this.

Answer (score 2):

```
json_decode(DIR.'config.json');
```

You are trying to decode the string `"<whatever-DIR-is>config.json"`. That's not a valid JSON string. You probably want:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents(DIR.'config.json'));
```

You also probably want more coffee.

Comment: Thanks for the coffee hint. That will tremendously enhance the quality of my code :-)